# I want to design a sql code to delete duplicates, the only thing is it is a bit more complex than just using a CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, sql-delete

Below is the how the table looks

```
PatientKey     Accotno     Date    EHR
yur567          123         4/5    HUB
yur567          123         4/5    REF 
yur789          780         4/9    HUB
yte789          567         7/8    HUB
yte765          569         7/7    REF
yte765          564         7/8    HUB
yur789          654         4/5    REF
yur789          654         4/5    HUB
```

I want to write a sql code so that where the patientKey is the same in both rows, delete REF and Keep HUB. At the sametime I dont want an other 'REF' data to be deleted. I only want to delete data where other REF(which are not duplicated to be deleted)

Desired Output:

```
PatientKey     Accotno     Date    EHR
yur567          123         4/5    HUB
yur789          780         4/9    HUB
yte789          567         7/8    HUB
yte765          569         7/7    REF
yte765          564         7/8    HUB
yur789          654         4/5    HUB
```

If you can see in the output all the data that had EHR=REF is deleted and  now we have unique rows.

Comment: In the example result, the `PatientKey` "yte765" is duplicated. Normal?

Comment: sorry that is my error, it is not suppose to be duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
delete t
from mytable t
where ehr = 'REF' and exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t1
    where t1.PatientKey = t.PatientKey and t1.date = t.date and t1.ehr = 'HUB'
)
```

This deletes "REF"s for which another "HUB" row exists for the same `date` and `PatientKey`.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to write a sql code so that where the patientKey is the same in both rows, delete REF and Keep HUB.

You can use `exists` to answer this question:

```
delete from t
    where t.ehr = 'REF' and
          exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.patientid = t.patientid and t2.ehr = 'HUB'
                 )
```

But based on your results, you seem to want to take other columns into account as well:

```
delete from t
    where t.ehr = 'REF' and
          exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.patientid = t.patientid and
                        t2.Accotno = t.Accotno and
                        t2.date = t.date and
                        t2.ehr = 'HUB'
                 )
```